# How can I get all the information about a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get all the information about a table, its columns and constraints etc in Oracle?  I am using

```
desc MY_TABLE
```

but that's only giving me column name, nullness and type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the dbms_metadata package , you can find more info [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/database-solutions/ddl-generationoracles-answer-to-save-you-time-and-money-7590)

Answer (score 1):

Check this script : http://oracletipstricks.blogspot.com/2008/01/getting-table-details-with-sqlplus.html

Give details :
- Column Details

- PRIMARY KEY
- INDEXES
- FOREIGN KEYS
- CONSTRAINTS
- ROWCOUNT
- Other Tables That REFER to this Table
- PARTITIONED COLUMNS
- PARTITIONS
- TRIGGERS
- DEPENDANTS

Answer (score 1):

You can use system tables to get the information you are looking for.

Check this link

http://techonthenet.com/oracle/sys_tables/index.php