# Finding table partition details

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get all the information about a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306876/how-can-i-get-all-the-information-about-a-table-in-oracle)

I need to add partitions into existing tables, we dont have production database access and we need to send sql queries to find details regarding existing partitions, I tried

```
desc <table-name>;
```

but it gives only info regarding table structure, we need table strucuture along with partition details.

Database is oracle 10g

Thanks

Comment: three seconds on google suggests select * from user_tab_partitions

Comment: I need complete DDL of tables along with structure. user_tab_partition will give info regarding partitions only. Is there one query which will give me entire DDL of table which we can see in third party tool (Toad, pl sql developer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_ddl` function of `dbms_metadata` package will give you such information:

```
SQL> create table Tb_Test(
  2    id number primary key
  3  )
  4  partition by range(id)(
  5    partition part1 values less than (100),
  6    partition part2 values less than (300),
  7    partition part3 values less than (maxvalue)
  8  )
  9  ;

Table created 

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TB_TEST')
  2    from dual
  3  ;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "BUDGET2011"."TB_TEST"
   (    "ID" NUMBER,

     PRIMARY KEY ("ID")

  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("ID")
 (PARTITION "PART1"  VALUES LESS THAN (100)
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" NOCOMPRESS ,
 PARTITION "PART2"  VALUES LESS THAN (300)
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" NOCOMPRESS ,
 PARTITION "PART3"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" NOCOMPRESS )
```